# How to get Flask app running with gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am new to Flask/Python and the question might be silly or I might be missing something obvious, so please bear with me.

I have created a Flask app and the structure is as follow:

```
myproject
  api
    __init__.py
    api.py
    application.py
    config.py
    models.py
  migrations
    ...
  appserver.py
  manage.py
  Procfile
  requirements.txt
```

The contents of my `appserver.py`:

```
from api.application import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
  create_app = create_app()
  create_app.run()
```

The contents of my `api/application.py`:

```
from flask import Flask


def create_app(app_name='MYAPPNAME'):
  app = Flask(app_name)
  app.config.from_object('api.config.DevelopmentConfig')

  from api.api import api
  app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api')

  from api.models import db
  db.init_app(app)

  return app
```

When I run my server locally with `python appserver.py` everything works as expected. When I try to run gunicorn like so: `gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 appserver:create_app` I get this error: `TypeError: create_app() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I would suggest you update the code inside the `appserver.py` files as shown below:

```
from api.application import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app = create_app()
    create_app.run()
else:
    gunicorn_app = create_app()
```

and then run the app as follows

```sh
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 appserver:gunicorn_app
```

The reason for the above steps is as follows:

**Running the server locally**

When you run the server locally with `python appserver.py` the `if` block gets executed. Hence the Flask object gets created via your `create_app` method and you are able to access the server.

**Running the server via Gunicorn**

When you run the server via Gunicorn, you need to specify the module name and the variable name of the app for Gunicorn to access it. Note that the variable should be a WSGI callable object for e.g a flask app object. This is as per the definition in [Gunicorn Docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn).

When you were running the Gunicorn command `gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 appserver:create_app`, it mistook `create_app` as the WSGI callable object(Flask app object). This threw the error as create_app is just a regular method which returns the Flask app object on correct invocation.

So we added the part of creating the object in the else block `gunicorn_app = create_app()` and called this via the Gunicorn using `gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 appserver:gunicorn_app`

The other thing that you need to note is when you run `python appserver.py` the `if` block gets triggered since it is the main file getting executed. Where as when you `gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 appserver:create_app` the `appserver.py` gets imported by gunicorn. Hence the `else` block gets triggered. This is the reason we have placed `gunicorn_app = create_app()` in the `else` block.

I hope the above explanation was satisfactory. Let me know if you have not understood any part.

Comment: Your suggestion works. Would you be able to expand a bit further and explain why it worked? That'd be very helpful for me as I'm learning :)

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK I have updated the answer. Let me know in case you are not able to understand. Glad that the answer was helpful. :)

Comment: Is there a way to specify --no-reload when running with Gunicorn? How can one manipulate the run parameters of the flask app if app.run() is not called in the else block?

Answer (score 19):

Pranav Kundaikar answer is excellent. I don't know if they updated `gunicorn` but I could avoid adding the `main` in my app using:

```
gunicorn -w 4 'api:create_app()'
```

Comment: Renan Ferreira Thank you. Your solution works as gunicorn allows function call as a variable name. This has been added in Nov 2019. This functionality  was not present when I posted the original answer. I checked since I was wondering how I missed out on it. Here is the gunicorn change for reference https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/commit/19cb68f4c3b55da22581c008659ee62d8c54ab2b

Thanks for sharing this update :)

Comment: The `-w 4` is irrelevant, maybe consider removing it from the answer so as to not imply it is needed.