# Using create_app() in Flask + App Engine + gunicorn

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, gunicorn

Flask uses an factory pattern to create the app object:

```
# myapp/__init__.py

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = True
    return app
```

In App Engine, `gunicorn` is used inside the `app.yaml` to start the app

```
  # ../myapp/app.yaml

  runtime: python37
  entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT myapp:create_app()
```

With this set up, I am getting a `Server Error` when I browse the app. In Stackdriver, I am getting the following error:

```
[start] 2020/02/25 16:19:45.268388 Start program failed: failed to detect app after start: ForAppStart(): [aborted, context canceled. subject:"app/valid" Timeout:30m0s, attempts:0 aborted, context canceled. subject:"app/invalid" Timeout:30m0s, attempts:0]
```

And also

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Here is the structure of my project:

```
project_root/
  app.yaml
  myapp/
    __init__.py  # << create_app() inside here
```

Comment: You don't have to use the function paranthesis in `create_app`, just call it without: `myapp:create_app` and have you also tried other paths? I don't know where exactly gunicorn will be started and what the relative path to your module really is. Maybe only calling `create_app` is enough (without `myapp:`)? The error message `failed to detect app` is clear. Gunicorn can't find `create_app` in module `myapp` as configured: `myapp:create_app`.

Comment: @colidyre, when using myapp:create_app I get this error `TypeError: create_app() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`. I don't understand where these arguments may be coming from. I have updated the question to include the project directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer inside [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395936/how-to-get-flask-app-running-with-gunicorn).

Inside `myapp/__init__.py` I needed to instantiate an app object

```
app = create_app()
```

The app.yaml now looks like this:

```
 entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT myapp:app
```

where `app` is the instantiated Flask app object.

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint is being passed to bash. You have to escape () with " i.e.

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT "myapp:create_app()"
```